# How to convert date from 2018-04-29 format to 29 Apr,2018 format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, formatting, momentjs

I have a date like this **2018-04-29** But I need the date in this format **29 Apr, 2018** How can i do it in `nodejs`?

I couldnot figure it out using [moment js](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Is there any other method?

Comment: `moment('2018-04-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD MMM, YYYY')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var givenDate = '2018-04-29'
var resultDate = moment(givenDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD MMM, YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

Well to get your date in the `29 Apr, 2018` format you can use two options:

1. Use **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)**:

You can use **[momentjs `.format()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/)**, like this:

```
var dateStr = '2018-04-29';
var dateWithMoment = moment(dateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD MMM, YYYY');
```

2. Or use **[`Date#toLocaleString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString)**.

You can use the [`toLocaleString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString) like this:

```
var options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric"
};
console.log((new Date(dateStr)).toLocaleString("en-US", options));
```

**Demo:**

This is a Demo showing both ways of doing this:

```js
var dateStr = '2018-04-29';
var dateWithMoment = moment(dateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD MMM, YYYY');

console.log(dateWithMoment);


var options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric"
};
console.log((new Date(dateStr)).toLocaleString("en-US", options));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If moment isn't working for you, you could use vanilla js like so:

```js
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

// Date to convert
let myDate = "2018-04-29";
let components = myDate.split('-'); 

// 29 Apr, 2018
let newDate = components[2] + " " +monthNames[parseInt(components[1]) - 1] +", " +components[0];
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Momentjs should do what you want just fine. (see Li357's answer).

If looking for alternatives, you may want to check out:

- https://date-fns.org/
- https://moment.github.io/luxon/